# Qualifier for Spanish

Tags: android

I want to localize my application to Spanish. Which qualifier should I use to accomplish this? For example, for Japanese we are using the "ja" qualifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be **es**

http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/06/localisation-internationalisation-on.html

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1

Answer (score 0):

### have you tried with es (España/Espanol)

edit:
oki a it more details in my answer

here in the table you have Language and region
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2

with 2 links 
http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/english_country_names_and_code_elements.htm

http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php

and those table should give you all the combinations you want

Answer (score 0):

it's "es" as in  "espanol"